# Page being displayed ok in Firefox is being cropped on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

My website is being cutted for some reason on IE8: http://testowa.portalo.pl/wiadomosci.php - I can't really find what's wrong.

Comment: can't remember if IE7 has this, but you should use the developer tools `F12` and play around with the CSS if anything strange looks like its happening again. you can turn on/off styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#Document` has css property `overflow` set as `hidden`.

If you make `overflow: visible;` for `#Document` specified in Line 14 of `stylesheet.css`, the problem goes.

```
#Document {
    Z-INDEX: 2; POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: left; WIDTH: 1003px; BACKGROUND: white; MARGIN-LEFT: auto; OVERFLOW: visible; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto; TOP: 0px; LEFT: -10px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `overflow:hidden` on your `#Document` element in your css.